# Can I use solver on pivot tables?

Tags: excel

I am trying to use solver on a pivot table. Is this possible? I am trying to change the sum to 60000. So in solver I set the value to 60000. But run into an issue of "objective cell contents must be a formula. So then I enter in a cell below the grand total = b35(or whatever the grand total cell is) And then I run into the issue of solver running into an error etc..

Any tips?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Solver relies on the sheet recalculating when the inputs are changed: this mechanism is missing from a Pivot Table, so I don't think your approach will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Solver on a pivot table to change the contents of the pivot table directly, as a pivot table's contents depends on other data.

In theory, you can use a value in a pivot table such as the sum as the cell to change by changing other cells, then set the cells to change to be at least some of the cells that are the source for the pivot table.